# Math.Pow in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, excel, math

Well obviously I'm doing something wrong but I'm stuck so I hope you will be able to help me out.

I have this equation in Excel: `=((247*(145/174)^3*60)/3600)*100`
Result = 238.233

And I have tried this in .Net:

```
(Math.Pow(247.0 * (145.0 / 174.0), Convert.ToDouble(3*60)) / 3600.0) * 100;
```

The problem is that C# returns a INF instead of the result and if I try to do this:

```
((long)Math.Pow(247.0 * (145.0 / 174.0), Convert.ToDouble(3*60)) / 3600.0) * 100;
```

The result does not match Excel.

Comment: What result you get? Add .0 to last 100 too. You have lots of constant numbers, to reduce confusion just put there total value instead o

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't give the same result as in Excel - And I know that the result in Excel is correct

Comment: You effectively changed the "bracketing" between Excel and .NET. `=((247*(145/174)^3*60)/3600)*100` in Excel is the same as `=(((247*(145/174)^3)*60)/3600)*100` but in .NET you're asking for `=((247*(145/174)^(3*60))/3600)*100`

Answer (score 10):

I suspect you should write as below:

```
247.0*Math.Pow(145.0/174.0,3)*60/3600*100;
```

See the fiddle here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/B32N3B

this is because in excel operator `^` ( rise to power ) has precedence against to `*`
so the intent of the excel line is to rise to `3` **then** multiply for `60`, **not** rise to `3*60`, that of course land to an overflow.

Comment: Yep this is certainly the answer. The C# code in the OP is raising the number to the power 180, which is obviously going to overflow.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thank you I did modify the answer to clarify ( I hope )

Comment: True, *if* the assumption is that the Excel calculation is correct in the first place.